# FindViewByID returns null when class was changed to another project as a reference

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My goal is to create a library class that I can take reference from other projects. Before, it is a whole project and there's no problem (Take picture, crop and other image processing). Then I transferred a part of my code to another project to try how to access other apps classes for future references. But after recreating the crop and other image processing as another project, some of it's part are not functioning well. In my crop image, SetContentView starts to prompt inflation exception and FindViewByID returns null.

I tried clean, rebuild, restart VS, delete app in mobile, recreate projects, clean and rebuild as often as I can, and deploy, deploy, deploy. Null returns are still there. Why?

This is my main launcher code

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

using ImageProcessingLibrary.Classes;
using ImageProcessingLibrary;
using BusinessObject;

namespace MenuApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "Camera", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar")]
    public class TakePicture : AppCompatActivity
    {
        //rest of code

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CameraLayout);

            //rest of code

            Button cropBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.crop_btn);

            cropBtn.Click += delegate 
            {
                //A simple intent to test the layout
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LayoutTest));
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
        }

        //rest of code
    }
}
```

and this is the code from another project referenced by main launcher

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Widget;

namespace ImageProcessingLibrary
{
    [Activity(Label = "LayoutTest", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar")]
    public class LayoutTest : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //This part returns inflate exception if inherits Activity and called from other project
            //After changing it to AppCompatActivity, exception is gone
            //But Activity or AppCompatActivity has no problem if independently deployed
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.croplayout);

            //All of FindViewById returns null
            var imageView = FindViewById<CropImageView>(Resource.Id.image);
            var btn1 = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.discard);
            var btn2 = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.save);
            var btn3 = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.rotateRight);
            var btn4 = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.rotateLeft);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the layout of layoutTest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageProcessingLibrary.CropImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <!--android:layout_x="0dip"
        android:layout_y="0dip"-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/discard"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_discard"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingRight="2dp"
          android:layout_weight="25" />
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/rotateRight"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_rotate_right"
          android:paddingLeft="2dp"
          android:paddingRight="2dp"
          android:layout_weight="25" />
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/rotateLeft"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_rotate_left"
          android:paddingLeft="2dp"
          android:paddingRight="2dp"
          android:layout_weight="25" />
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/save"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_save"
          android:paddingLeft="2dp"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:layout_weight="25" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The LayoutTest is my testing area inside project of crop image to test the layout and findviewbyid problems. It is main launcher so I can test it independently (no problem with findviewbyid if independently deployed, only if referenced by other project). What are the possible reason of this?

Comment: Did you create dependency? Project should be dependant of library.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is xamarin so I put it in reference then call it by using the name space. Do I still need to create dependency in xamarin?

Comment: No, reference should be enough. As my thought, Xamarin may not merge resources, as "clean" Android, but them should be accessible using namespace. I recommend you to analyse compiled dll to find out, where are your resources and how to correctly address them.

Comment: If you are familiar with business layers, my other class library is business object where strings and other objects resides. It is working well and referenced by both project (Take Picture Project and Crop Project). I'm just really having problem in this library that contains activities too. I'll wait for others answer while testing it too :)